# Como integrar SlmQueueSqs e SlmMail em uma aplicação ZF2?

Tags: php, zend, amazon-aws

Estou dando manutenção em uma aplicação desenvolvida no Zend Framework 2 e preciso, nessa ordem:

- Enviar tarefas para uma fila no AWS SQS.
- Processar as tarefas da fila por meio de um comando da aplicação que usará o AWS SES.

Encontrei dois componentes interessantes para fazer essas duas tarefas: o [SlmQueueSqs](https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmQueue) e o [SlmMail](https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmMail). Entretanto, por não ter muita prática com ZF2, estou apanhando um pouco para implementar esses recursos.

O que foi feito até agora:

- A aplicação envia e-mails em sincronia com a requisição; para evitar a sobrecarga dos servidores, preciso colocar o corpo do email e o destinatário em uma fila SQS.
- Customizei a aplicação com as chaves AWS no arquivo `aws.local.php`.
- Mandei carregar os módulos necessários: `Aws`, `SlmQueue` e `SlmQueueSqs`.
- Criei o comando que rodará todos os minutos para pegar os elementos que estão na fila e disparar os e-mails via SES, mas ainda falta a integração com o próprio SES.

As documentações necessárias estão nos links acima – entretanto, por não ter muita prática para trabalhar com o container de serviços do ZF2, não consegui segui-las à risca até agora.

Comment: Não sei se a sua questão é válida pois é muito vaga e não indica um problema específico para resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que o pressuposto que essa solução vai evitar sobrecarregar o seu servidor, é falso. Vou tentar explicar de forma simples porque esta é uma confusão comum.

Para enviar mensagens para uma fila de email da Amazon, você vai dar sobrecarga no seu servidor para compor mensagens, conectar com o servidor de filas, e enviar a mensagem.

Se você usar um servidor de email local (tipo sendmail/postfix/qmail), o efeito é o mesmo, pois quando você chama a função mail, a mensagem não é enviada para o destino imediatamente. Normalmente a mensagem vai para uma fila local, e só mais tarde o servidor de email tenta enviar.

Para além disso, quando você se conecta com o servidor da Amazon, você usa uma conexão TCP/IP que é muito mais lenta que a conexão com servidor de email local que é apenas uma comunicação entre processos (pipes), ou seja, o PHP demora muito menos tempo e CPU a colocar as mensagens no servidor local do que a enviar para o servidor de filas da Amazon.

Agora para enviar email em massa usando PHP, é possível realizar algumas otimizações que fazem o processo demorar muito menos tempo e gastar muito menos CPU nas versões de PHP mais recentes, tal como [está explicado neste artigo](http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/enviando-email-em-massa-rapidamente-em-php-usando-otimizacoes-inteligentes/).